# Exporting excel reports

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, export-to-excel

I have a software ready in which i am exporting excel reports through code in ASP.NET . 
Right now I am developing the entire on Localhost , so when i export the report it is downloading on my PC .
I am just concerned if i run it on live server and than I export the excel reports , will it download on my Pc or on server.

```
  public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
        {
            if (!General.ValidateSession())
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
            }
            string fDate = TempData["FromDate"].ToString();
            string tDate = TempData["toDate"].ToString();
            var grdview = new GridView();
            grdview.DataSource = this.GetList();
            grdview.DataBind();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= " + fDate + " - " + tDate + ".xls ");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";
            StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(strWriter);
            grdview.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
            Response.Output.Write(strWriter.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
            return RedirectToAction("DateRecords");
        }
```

Comment: How would the server know about your computer?

Comment: This is my question @JamesFaix

Comment: when you host to server and export to EXCEL, it will be downloaded to the user's machine from where  your application  is accessed

Comment: @user9405863 Thanks! so it means I don't need to change or don't need to give any path on the above code ?

Comment: @ArhamKhan yes. it will download to the client machine.

Comment: @user9405863 Thanks

Comment: @ArhamKhan Sorry for the misunderstanding.  I thought you were asking if it would always get downloaded to the development machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you host the application on server and  On EXCEL Export, file will be downloaded to the user's machine  from the server. not on to your  local machine!